# Convert CGFloat to NSNumber in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, casting, nsnumber, cgfloat

I have an extension in Swift that holds some properties which are `CGFloat`'s. The problem is that I don't know how to get the store the `CGFloat` value as a `NSNumber` using the associated objects

Here is the code I have that doesn't work but it details what I want to do:

```
var scaledFontSize: CGFloat {
    get {
        guard let fontSize = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &AssociatedKeys.scaledFontSize) as? NSNumber else {
            //Set it
            let scaledFont:CGFloat = VGSizeValues.getValueFromValue(self.font.pointSize);
                //Fails here
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self,&AssociatedKeys.scaledFontSize, NSNumber( scaledFont),objc_AssociationPolicy.OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC)
            return scaledFont;
        }
        return CGFloat(fontSize.doubleValue);

    }
}
```

Does anyone way to work around this?

Comment: let floatInNumber = NSNumber(float: Float(floatValue))

Answer (score 72, accepted):

In Swift 3.0

```
let myFloat : CGFloat = 1234.5

let myNumber = NSNumber(value: Float(myFloat))
```

or

```
let myNumber = NSNumber(value: Double(myFloat))
```

In Swift 2

```
let myNumber = NSNumber(double: myFloat.native)
```

or

```
let myNumber = NSNumber(double: Double(myFloat))
```

or

```
let myNumber = NSNumber(float: Float(myFloat))
```

Comment: the problem with  let myNumber = NSNumber(value: Float(myFloat)) is that I lose precision CGFloat 0.4 => Float 0.400000006

Answer (score 11):

For Swift 3.1

```
var final_price: CGFloat = 12.34
let num = final_price as NSNumber
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer

Answer (score 7):

**Swift 3**

`let myNumber = NSNumber(value: Float(myCGFloat))`

Answer (score 2):

You can access a CGFloat's `NativeType` via the `native` property:

```swift
public var native: CGFloat.NativeType
```

> The native type used to store the CGFloat, which is Float on 32-bit architectures and Double on 64-bit architectures.

With this you can create an `NSNumber` like so:

```swift
NSNumber(value: cgFloat.native)
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer! By using `Float(cgFloat)` you may be loosing precision if the native type is a `Double`. `NSNumber(value: cgFloat.native)` is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

For me this is worked.

```
self.configuration.cellHeight as NSNumber!
```